# What is the difference between these sending methods in python scapy?

Tags: python

```
from scapy.all import *
```

1 - LAYER 3 :

```
layer3 = IP(src='127.0.0.1', dst='127.0.0.1')
```

The result when i use `sr()` or `sr1()` the same as below:

```
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

The result when i use `send()`:

```
Sent 1 packets.
```

2 - LAYER 2:

```
layer2 = Ether(src='11:22:33:44:55:66', dst='11:22:33:44:55:66')
```

The result when i use srp() or srp1() the same as below:

```
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

The result when i use `sendp()`:

```
Sent 1 packets.
```

I know `sr()` and `sr1()` and `send()` are for layer 3 and `srp()` and `srp1()` and `sendp()` are for layer 2

my question is what is the difference between the functions that are in layer 3 and what is the difference between the functions that are in layer 2 ?

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between layer 2 (in this case, ethernet frames) and layer 3 (in this case, IP packets), or something specific to this framework?

Comment: no i am asking about the difference between the functions that are in layer 2 which are : srp() and srp1() and sendp() and the functions that are in layer 3 which are : sr() and sr1() and send() because i am getting tha same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The send() function will send packets at layer 3. That is to say, it will handle routing and layer 2 for you. The sendp() function will work at layer 2. It's up to you to choose the right interface and the right link layer protocol.
read [documents](https://0xbharath.github.io/art-of-packet-crafting-with-scapy/scapy/sending_recieving/index.html#send) please for more informations

Comment: thank you so much the documentation was a cool tutorial